# ReactJS: rending 100 divs without any rendering hiccups

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, performance, render

I have a component that renders 100 divs:

```
  return (hive.map((hex)=>
          <div
            key={hex.id}
            id={hex.id}
            className={`hex hex-zoom-out`}
            style={{ width: hex.width, height: hex.height, top: hex.top, left: hex.left }}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(hex.html)}
            onClick={(e)=>hex.link ? window.open(hex.link, "_blank") : console.log(e.target.style)}
            onMouseOver={(e)=>hex.link ? '' : e.target.style.cursor = 'default'}
            onMouseEnter={(e)=>startAnimation(e)}
          />
      )
```

**PROBLEM:** I have an animated loader icon visible before the data that will fill the array is fetched. This icon will fade out once the data has been fetched and then the dom renders the 100 divs. At this point the loader, while fading out, stutters a little. It is a minor issue but since I'm trying to make it graphically pleasing it's annoying to see this issue.

How can I fix it? I was thinking of adding gradually the divs to the screen (it is acceptable for my case).

I tried using some timeouts but with no luck.

Comment: Use [keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)?

Comment: Maybe [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can help here

Comment: Have you verified that it flickers in a prod build?  Sometimes when you strip out all the development helpers in a dev build you see some performance improvements at the outer margins...

Comment: Did you try windowing? More info at https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists